# One point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

I would like to know if this is correct. Let $Y=\mathbb{R}\cup\{\partial\mathbb{R}\}$ be the one point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$. Is $U=\left(-\infty,-1\right)\cup\left(1,\infty\right)\cup\{\partial\mathbb{R}\}$ an example of an open set in $Y$? The complement of $U$ with respect to $\mathbb{R}$ is $\left[-1,1\right]$ which is closed and compact in $\mathbb{R}$ so it seems so.

Also, are $a_n=n$ and $b_n=-n$ sequences which both converge to $\partial\mathbb{R}$? Clearly both sequences have terms which lie in $U$ but I do not know if every open set in $Y$ is similar to the form of $U$, where those open sets have 'tails' that include a neighbourhood of $\pm\infty$.

Comment: The answer to both of your questions is *yes*. The sets of the form $Y\setminus[-n,n]$ are a base of open nbhds at the point $\partial\Bbb R$, so any sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in $\Bbb R$ such that $\lim_n|x_n|=\infty$ converges to $\partial\Bbb R$.

Comment: For a geometric interpretation of this situation, note the the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to the circle, $S^1$. (What does the proposed neighborhood look like in $S^1$?)

Comment: Would it be a set of points around the top of the circle? I guess one could picture a circle unraveling itself from the top and being stretched to the real line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that in one-point compactification of $X$ : $X \cup \{\infty\}$ a set is open if it is a subset of $X$ and is open, or if it is of the form $\{\infty\}\cup U$, where $U \subset X$ has compact complement.

In you example, $U = (\mathbb{R} \setminus [-1; 1])\cup \{\partial\mathbb{R}\}$. Since $[-1; 1]$ is compact, $U$ is indeed an open subset of one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}$.

You are right, both this sequences converge to $\partial \mathbb{R}$, since any it's neighbourhood contains a tail of both sequences. [Brian M. Scotts' comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1752542/one-point-compactification-of-mathbbr#comment3576303_1752542) tells that it is due to sets like $U$ being a neighbourhood base.

Comment: lisyarus, should the complement of $U$ be closed as well? I know in my example the condition of being closed is redundant but in more general topological spaces, is the condition of being closed necessary in the definition?

Comment: @user333434 In general, the one-point compactification is done for locally compact, noncompact Hausdorff spaces, and in Hausdorff spaces any compact set is also closed. Note that in general in non-Hausdorff spaces compact sets need not be closed, but one-point compactification doesn't work in this spaces either.